# How to become an ISP

Tags: networking, internet, isp

well cutting to the point...

I want to be able to provide internet to rural areas of my country so they can too gain acces to internet for free.

I was wondering what I need to start small, like provide internet on a block or something, hoping eventually this can be big enough for anyone to use.

I hope you guys could point me out to the right direction(If you could also help it would be awesome).

I hope you have a great day :D

Comment: What background do you have for this? I assumed that you knew all the networking transport and were just unfamiliar with the logistics of getting routable IP blocks. You should give us more details.

Comment: You see my background comes from the software area but I would like to get my hands on this kind of knowledge, you see, everywhere you ask people instead of telling you where to start they just tell you "you're crazy" Instead of just pointing out good books to start with.

Matthew told me something about learning OSS/BSS but I thought those were needed if you had a plan of business.(Which in this case not even close on getting it to business when Its merely an idea waiting to be executed).

My guess is I need some pointing out to where do I start?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please don't be offended, but if you don't know the answer to this question, you're not ready to do this. System and network administration at the service provider level requires some pretty in depth industry knowledge. The OSS/BSS involved (operational support systems, business support systems) alone could take years to learn. There's a reason why internetworking engineers get paid as much as they do. A good place to start would be looking at firewall.cx, and picking up some cisco books to learn the basics.

Answer (score 4):

LEARN how to run a network.

Contact an ISP to get an address block and a link.

IMplement technology to get customers on line, sign contracts, collect money.

Which part do you now know? For me this is a shopping question (voted to close). ISP network side is basic administration.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've got all the infrastructure to provide network connectivity on your end, what you need to link it to the world is a routable address block. There are two types of routable address blocks: portable and non-portable.

Portable blocks are owned by you and assigned by your [Regional Internet Registry (RIR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry). You can use them to link to any ISP, take them with you, they're yours. They're also scarce and expensive.

Non-portable address space can come from some larger ISP who carves out a block for you. You will lose the use of those addresses should you end your business relationship, but they may be more available for less up-front cost.

Once you've got yourself a route to the 'net / larger service provider accepting your traffic, the rest is just making packets flow within your network. That's the hard part ;)